# C# - What is the best way to serialize list of objects to files?

Tags: .net, serialization

I saw some techniques :

1. serialize to XML file with XmlSerializer and system.IO.File class
2. serialize to XML file with XmlSerializer and streamWriter
3. serialize to bin file with BinaryFormatter and File Class

Is there any difference between them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 & 2 are basically the same, serializing XML to a stream/file.  #3 would write a much smaller footprint than other options.

Comment: So the better way is with the BinaryFormatter class instead of XmlSerialization ?

Is there something  else better ?

Thanks.

Comment: as always it depends, I would use binary to stream over the wire, but if you want to be able to actually look at the output then XML is nice but it's fat...  Binary would always be more efficient than any other option outside of writing your own binary serializer.

Comment: @RonenB if you want others to read your serialized data, you can go `xml` if you don't care about readability go `binary`

Comment: @adricadar - I will go with the binary.
I dont need others to read it, just to save list of objects to files during changes of information and "pull" it back when the program is up .
It's a little project that i'm doing - I'm a new c# programmer.
Thank you :)

Comment: @RonenB if you are learning, maybe is better **to see what you stored** it will help you to understand and to debug more easily.

Answer (score 1):

Between 1 and 2 there is no difference at **output** you will get an `xml` file structure that may look something like this **human readable**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<myList>
   <object>1</object>
   <object>2</object>
</myList>
```

For 3 binay you objects will be store in [binary format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) this mean that is **machine readable**, and can look like this

```
100101010111010101110101010...10101
```

**Conlusion**: If you want others (or you) to read your serialized data go `xml`, if you don't care about readability go `binary`.